# Multiple values in SQL CASE's THEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am wondering if it is possible to specify multiple values in the then part of a case statement in `T-SQL`?

I have attached a chunk of code where I am using this to join in some tables in a query. I have included a comment in the snippet.

```
LEFT JOIN Business B ON v.BusID = B.BusID
LEFT JOIN BusinessTypeKey T ON B.BusinessTypeID = T.BusTypeID
LEFT JOIN Location L ON L.BusID = B.BusID
AND L.HeadQuarters = CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) from Location L2
WHERE L2.BusID = B.BusID) = 1                                                                           
THEN 1,0   -- Would like to specify either 1 or 0 here. I suppose I could also make it euqal to -> L.HeadQuarters but would like a better way to impose it                                                                                                  
ELSE 1  
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little ugly, but assuming HeadQuarters is not a decimal/numeric type and only integer values,

```
AND L.HeadQuarters BETWEEN CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT...) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AND 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean...?

```
LEFT JOIN whatever
ON...
CASE...WHEN...THEN...END = 1
OR
CASE...WHEN...THEN...END = 0
```