# SQL Server- CASE WHEN THEN in list- multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I know that SQL CASE will not accept `in list` for the `then` part of the `CASE` statement.

What I am ideally looking for is such a case:

```
CASE WHEN 'A' Then in list ['B' , 'C'] ELSE 'A' END
```

or

```
CASE WHEN 'A' Then 'B' or 'C' ELSE 'A' END
```

I am using this CASE Statement as a part of Designing a SQL view.

Just to let you know, I have already checked [Multiple values in SQL CASE's THEN Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945660/multiple-values-in-sql-cases-then-statment) and the answer there didn't work for me.

EDIT, PROBLEM Description and Dummy Data:

My main table is  `dbo.main` 
In this table I have data in form

```
Year    CTG
2015    A
2015     B
2015    C
2015    D
```

In my design view I worte this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR, 'GENRL' AS SETID, '000001' AS LABOR_AGREEMENT, CTG
FROM            dbo.main
```

Now my ultimate goal is to have below table:

```
Year    CTG
2015    B/C
2015     B
2015    C
2015    D
```

The `CTG` value is a key to initiate another table in another page, and I want that table to show all the values for **CTG: B** and **CTG:C**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  `CASE WHEN 'A' THEN 'B' OR 'C' ...` doesn't exactly make sense.  What are you trying to do when it is `A`?

Comment: I want to have the result as both b and c

Comment: `case` returns one value from several distinct choices (of the same type), and that's how it is. If you want to return a conditionally populated `table` variable, you would need a function or SP (or possibly a clever CTE can do this; I don't know...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to write a SP then, if you have any suggestion for a SP to satisfy this condition, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide some dummy sample data and a more complete sql statement so we have a better idea of what you want.

Comment: @Tanner sure I will add it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a searched `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CTG = 'A' THEN 'B/C'
             ELSE CTG
        END)
FROM dbo.main
```

Actually, this works with a simple `CASE` as well:

```
SELECT (CASE CTG WHEN 'A' THEN 'B/C'
             ELSE CTG
        END)
FROM dbo.main
```

Comment: This 'B/C' that you provided is just a simple text. "/" in my code means or.

Comment: what do you mean by or here? you also said you want both:  
"I want to have the result as both b and c – user 12321 16 mins ago"

Comment: is it an 'or' or an 'and'?

Comment: @user12321 . . . `'B/C'` is taken directly from your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "or" posibility for a single field in a single row. A single colunm (field) can contain one value in a single row. What you ask for, sounds like can be solved with a second column with the extra value (when the case aplies, or null), or instead (but not addressed in your question) an extra row with the extra value on it.
As you comment that you want "values" but not concatenation (or something else), you can generate the extra column to fit the second value when it applies like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR, 'GENRL' AS SETID, '000001' AS LABOR_AGREEMENT, 
CASE WHEN CTG='A' THEN 'B' ELSE CTG END AS CTG,
CASE WHEN CTG='A' THEN 'C' END          AS CTGbis -- else null    is the default behavior
FROM dbo.main
```